# convergence of modulus BM under a subsequence

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Is it true that if $B$ is a BM, then there exists a subsequence $t_n$ such that $|B_{t_n}| \to \infty$ almost surely? Does this follow from the law of the iterated logarithm directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not follow immediately from LIL. LIL only gives you a sequence depending on $\omega$.

Consider $P(\frac 1 {|B_{t_n}|} >\epsilon) =P(|B_{t_n}| <\frac 1 {\epsilon})$. Since $B_{t_n} = \sqrt t_n X$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$ we get $\sum_n P(\frac 1 {|B_{t_n}|} > \epsilon)=\sum_n P(|X| <\frac 1 {\epsilon \sqrt {t_n}}) \leq \sum_n \frac 2 {\sqrt {2\pi} \epsilon \sqrt {t_n}}$ Using the fact that $e^{-x^{2}/2} \leq 1$.  This last sum is finite if $t_n >2^{2n}$. By Borel - Cantelli Lemma we see that $|B_{t_n}| \to \infty $ almost surely.

Comment: I did not fully understand your last inequality. $P(|X| < \frac{1}{\epsilon \sqrt{t_n}} ) = 2 \frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{1/\epsilon \sqrt{t_n}} exp(- \frac{1}{2} s^2) ds \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} (\frac{1}{\epsilon \sqrt{t_n}} + \int_{-\infty}^0 exp( - \frac{1}{2} s^2) ds $. How do I get rid of the second summand? It is $\int_{-\infty}^0 exp( - \frac{1}{2} s^2) ds = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}$ right?

Comment: @BenC. $P(|Y| <a)=\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx$ if $f$ is the density of $Y$.

Comment: Oh, stupid of me. Thank you very much for your quick answer.